# How to bypassed SSH password prompt in bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write script that will allow me to execute same command on 100 Hosts.
This is what I have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS='host1 host2 ...host100'
for host in $HOSTS; do
ssh usrname@$host sudo swapon -a -f && cat /proc/swaps
done
```

But the issue is that it is promting me for my passowrd everytime. 
I did some reserach and unfortunately cannot use expect , sshpass , Public Key Authentication or any programs that requires me to install anything.
Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: can you provide more details on your constraints? like why those solutions you listed don't work for you? for example if it's a lack of admin privileges, you can compile things from source and install for your specific user account

Comment: Just pointing out that you won't need to install anything for Public key Authentication to work. Though, I can imagine if this would not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: I have root access but my company does not allow me to install or modify anything. and expect  does not work as I have to put my password in plain text .

Comment: Why can't you use public key authentication? The only thing you would be "installing" is a tiny text file.